# How to highlight match if grep does not support color option

Tags: grep

I'm posting this question here, because I didn't find it elsewhere (SO/Google).

I'm working with "HP-UX 11i Version 3" (at least from `man grep`) and grep does not support `--color` option so I was looking for a workaround.

I found some way that works for me (using perl) and I'd say there are other similar (sed, maybe awk and so on), but maybe something completely different.

Answer (score 0):

Answer here on SO - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/8417/29677 worked well in  my environment, I created shell script:

```
grep $1 | perl -pe 's/'$1'/\e[1;31m$&\e[0m/g'
```

Works pretty fine, I'm still testing it, one side effect I noticed is, that original `grep --color A | grep --color B` highlights on Bs, but this solution also highlights As also, but I consider that as a feature.